# Cannot open database 'dbTest' requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'testUser'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection, ssms

Why do I get an error

> The login failed

from this code?

```
try
{
    string connectionString;
    SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    SqlClient.SqlConnection connection;

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    connectionString = "Server=IP,PORT;Database=dbTest;Integrated Security=False;User ID=testUser;Password=XXXXXX;";

    connection = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    dataAdapter = new SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connection);
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblTest");

    dataSet.Dispose();
    dataAdapter.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

It works fine with a local database, but with a remote database, it throws that  "login failed" error.

**Note 1**: I can login to the server with this userID and password using the SQL Server Management Studio.

**Note 2**: below code works but why and what's the difference?

```
try
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

    DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=IP,PORT;Database=dbTest;Integrated Security=False;User ID=testUser;Password=XXXXXX;";

    using (connection)
    {
        DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        command.Connection = connection;

        DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was just the connection string. When I changed it to:

```
connectionString = "Data Source=IP;Initial Catalog=dbTest;Integrated Security=false;User ID=testUser;Password=XXXXXX;"
```

, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide provider name in your connection variable.

```
connectionString = "Server=IP,PORT;Database=dbTest;Integrated Security=False;" + 
                   "User ID=testUser;Password=XXXXXX;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient";
```

Answer (score 0):

> it works with local database perfectly but with remote db throw login
>   failed error.

It seems you have a trouble with remote connection on your SQL Server.

Please review next links:

https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UkHYNwUtCo